# Flex Tree Properties, Null Reference?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, tree

I am pulling down a large XML file and I have no control over it's structure.

I used a custom function to use the tag name to view the tree structure as a flex tree, but then it breaks.  I am guessing it has something to do with my other function, one that calls attribute values from the selected node.

See code.

```
<mx:Tree x="254" y="21" width="498" height="579" id="xmllisttree"       labelFunction="namer" dataProvider="{treeData}" showRoot="false"  change="treeChanged(event)" />
```

//and the Cdata

```
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent; 
[Bindable] private var fullXML:XMLList;  
private function contentHandler(evt:ResultEvent):void{  
    fullXML = evt.result.page;  
}  

[Bindable]
public var selectedNode:Object;

public function treeChanged(event:Event):void {
selectedNode=Tree(event.target).selectedItem;
}

 public function namer(item:Object):String {
        var node:XML = XML(item);
        var nodeName:QName = node.name();
        var stringtest:String ="bunny";
            return nodeName.localName;
        }
```

The error is TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Where is the null reference?

Comment: Are you using FlexBuilder?  If you are, have you tried setting a breakpoint in your code?  Does the TypeError report a line number in the stack trace?

Comment: I think it's pretty difficult to understand your problem from the code you provide : namer is never called, no xml file is loaded. It's easier to help you if you provide a sample of code allowing to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Axelle  Labelfunction is listed in the XML that points to the included code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. It sounds like your XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <test>
    <child>leaf 1</child>
  </test>
  <test2>
    <child2>leaf 2</child2>
  </test2>
</root>
```

The significant part of this is that there is simple content within the child and child2 tags.  Expanding the tree to show 'leaf 1' or 'leaf 2' causes the error you are receiving, because node.name() will return null.  This makes sense, because 'leaf 1' and 'leaf 2' are text nodes and don't have node names.

To correct the problem, you can update the namer function to something along these lines:

```
public function namer(item:Object):String {
    var node:XML = XML(item);
    var nodeName:QName = node.name();
    if (nodeName) {
        return nodeName.localName;
    } else {
        return String(node);
    }
}
```

This will use 'leaf 1' and 'leaf 2' as the label for the corresponding nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging this in flex builder or eclipse?

The most likely candidate for your null reference error is the 'item' argument passed to namer().  The tree component does pass a string through to the labelFuntion method but it may not be a string that can be converted to an xml object.  I'd definitely check that first.

The other thing that I can see is wrong is that you are accessing localName as if it's a property.  It's actually method so you should be calling it by nodeName.localName().  **Edit... this is incorrect now as i didn't realise nodeName was of type QName. localName is actually a property of this type. appologies**

Edit: also your Tree component has a dataProvider of

```
dataProvider="{treeData}"
```

From the example you have given it doesn't look like treeData exists. Should that be fullXML?

Answer (score 0):

According to Flex and the guy who answered my other question (Herreman) calling localname as a property is the right way to do things.

fullXML and that stringtest line are artifacts.  I have the XML embedded in the same file atm.

It fails on return nodeName.localName when it is trying to draw the leaf nodes.
SO I know it has something to do with:

```
return nodeName.localName;
```

and

```
public function treeChanged(event:Event):void {
selectedNode=Tree(event.target).selectedItem;
}
```

Comment: local name is a method. should be "return nodeName.localName();" Not sure if that is the only problem or not.